# Why classes that implements Serializable interface implements none interface's methods?

Tags: java, serialization, implementation

I thought class that implements an interface **must** implement all of the interface's methods,why classes that implements Serializable interface implements none interface's methods ?

Comment: There are no mandatory methods to implement. Its a marker interface.

Comment: The answer I was looking for was the fact that if you send a serialized class that has inside a nested class and isn't marked as serializable the object will be sent without the nested class .It's a way to distinguish which classes want to be send.

Comment: it will only send the *objects* you ask it to. It doesn't send classes, and it doesn't care if a class has inner classes whether they are marked Serializable or not.

Comment: *OK it sends objects and you mark the classes*. If you have a class (a JPanel) with some buttons and the actionlistener is implemented to a nested class if you send that object and you haven't marked the nested class as Serializable the button will not respond to any action (as an example).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why do you want to serialize a JPanel with an action to be displayed on another machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some interfaces act simply as markers for classes. Serializable is one of them. The methods are there only in case your object requires special handling in order to be serialized and deserialized.

Answer (score 3):

Because `Serializable` is only a "marker" interface for object serialization and has no methods defined. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only
>   to identify the semantics of being serializable.

And from [SDN](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/):

> An object is marked serializable by implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface, which signifies to the underlying API
>   that the object can be flattened into bytes and subsequently inflated
>   in the future.